# Putting a react component (or element?) in an object.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am making a table on my react website with [react-bootstrap-table-next](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2) (also known as react-bootstrap-table-2) and am trying to get an icon component to show up in the rows as data instead of what I have now, which is an x, like this: [image]

A sample of what I currently have for data is:

```
const tools = [{key: 'Android Mobile', qual: "x"}]
```

But what I want to do is something like:

```
const tools = [{key: 'Android Mobile', qual: <CheckIcon/>}]
```

Where CheckIcon is `const CheckIcon = () => <Icon icon={check} size={10}/>` (where Icon is being imported from `react-icons-kit`).

Currently the entire page does not render when I do something like that, and I haven't been able to find much information on how to insert a component into an object with React. If there are any tips or tricks anyone has, that would be much appreciated!

[Here is a stackblitz for anyone that wants to play around with the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-table-problem?file=index.js)

Comment: You should store a state. Not the component. `qual: true` or `qual: false`. Then in your template do `this.state.qual` to should or hide the component.

Comment: That's true, I guess I didn't think about that before, but it still begs the question of how to get the check icon component to display in the table

Comment: Build your own table? lol! Just skimming the docs, doesn't look like it lets you pass in child components. I would look to make sure.

Comment: Lol fair, just trying to see if I can be lazy and take this route haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`column.formatter`](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnformatter-function) can help you. there's a online demo: [this](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Column%20Formatter&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that `react-bootstrap-table-next` props data accept React Component.

So far what I've found it does not support render a React Component inside the data object.
https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/blob/master/packages/react-bootstrap-table2/src/bootstrap-table.js#L118

Feel free if you want to submit a new feature at https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming to the same conclusion as @Roman Masyhar and ended up taking the cheater's route for now until I end up just making my own table and just using the "✔" character in place of x's and just styling them for the same effect

In case anyone is curious I did also open a [feature request here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/400)